# не работает функция printf

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Только начала изучать PHP, и вот появился вопрос: пытаюсь вывести с помощью 
printf данные, а тестовый сервер пишет:"Ошибка разбора: ошибка разбора, неожиданный `T_ECHO` в `y:\home\reg\www\php\mysql.php` на линии 20".С помощью оператора echo все получается. А здесь нет, может, что-то не так в синтаксисе? Сама ошибку найти не могу, вот код:

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
  printf("Сотрудник № - %s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br><br>",echo $myrow['id'],echo $myrow['name'],echo $myrow['lastname'],echo $myrow['dol']);
}

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    printf("$myrow Сотрудник № - %s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br><br>", $myrow['id'], $myrow['name'], $myrow['lastname'], $myrow['dol']);
}
```

Изменения: вместо do-while используется while (так как нет гарантии, что по запросу вернулась хотя бы одна строка) и убраны echo.

П.С.: А у вас так и задумано, чтобы строки начинались на "Array Сотрудник ..."?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! Извините, плиз, это ошибка, просто я уже как только не переписывала код.

Comment: Все получилось, виноват лишний echo, все из-за невнимательности...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала
вот так вот оформить код

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do { printf("Сотрудник № - %s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br><br>",echo $myrow['id'],echo $myrow['name'],echo $myrow['lastname'],echo $myrow['dol']); }

while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Второе [printf](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) читаем документацию.

и не пишем вот так

```
printf("Сотрудник № - %s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br><br>",echo $myrow['id'],echo $myrow['name'],echo $myrow['lastname'],echo $myrow['dol']);
```

Хотя бы так примерно, зачем в выводе на экран делать еще вывод на экран?

```
printf("$myrow Сотрудник № - %s<br>%s<br>%s<br>%s<br><br>",$myrow['id'], $myrow['name'],['lastname'],$myrow['dol']);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, документацию читала, но до вашего примера толком не поняла, спасибо, попробую, сейчас все понятно!